# CSS3 Crossfading various images

Tags: html, image, css

I have 4 images that I would like to crossfade using CSS inside a container:

```
<div id="frame">
    <img class="img1" src="img1.jpg">
    <img class="img2" src="img2.jpg">
    <img class="img3" src="img3.jpg">
    <img class="img4" src="img4.jpg">
</div>
```

I know that crossfading images consists of a CSS animation, but I haven't been able to find the CSS to make it work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M33vn/)

It's easier with 2 pictures, but as your wrote 4 you need to do this as CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

#Crossfading {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#Crossfading img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}

#Crossfading img {
  -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;

  -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-duration: 8s;

  -o-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-duration: 8s;

  animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 8s;
}
#Crossfading img:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
#Crossfading img:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
#Crossfading img:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
#Crossfading img:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  animation-delay: 0;
}
```